# Need help understanding scope of variables in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, loops, scope

I'm doing a small program for school where it reads in a data file and outputs the results in the console. I'm having problems figuring out why my array of objects doesn't carry over after I finish a while loop. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class order{
    private static Node nodes[];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String dataFile = "file.dat";
        indegreeCompute(dataFile);
    }

    private static void indegreeCompute(String dataFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File(dataFile));
        nodes = new Node[scanFile.nextInt()];
        while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
            scanFile.nextLine();
            int index = scanFile.nextInt();
            System.out.print("node = " + index);
            scanFile.next();
            int NumOutDegree = scanFile.nextInt();
            nodes[index].outDegree = NumOutDegree;
            System.out.print(" outDegree = " + nodes[index].outDegree);
            nodes[index].adjNodes = new int[NumOutDegree];
            scanFile.next();
            System.out.print(" adjNodes = [");
            for ( int i = 0; i < nodes[index].outDegree; i ++ ) {
                nodes[index].adjNodes[i] = scanFile.nextInt();
                if (i < nodes[index].outDegree - 1)
                    System.out.print(nodes[index].adjNodes[i] + ", ");
                else
                    System.out.print(nodes[index].adjNodes[i]);
            }
            System.out.print("]");
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i ++) {
            int outDegree = nodes[i].outDegree;
            for(int k = 0; k < outDegree; k ++) {
                int adjNode = nodes[i].adjNodes[k];
                nodes[adjNode].inDegree ++;
            }
        }
        scanFile.close();
    }
}
```

The part I'm having issues with specifically is the last part with the for loop. I'm trying to use the information from the array I created in my while loop but when I debug, it's showing my node array with wrong values.

The auxiliary class is just this:

```
public class Node {
    public static int inDegree, outDegree, adjNodes[];
}
```

Any help or explanation to help me understand would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the contents of the file:

```
14 //numNodes; space after '(' and before ')' to simplify reading the file
 0 (  1 ): 10 //node ( outdegree ): adjNodes in arbitrary order
 1 ( 10 ):  0  5  8 10  6  9  7 11 12 13
 2 (  1 ):  7
 3 (  3 ):  1  10 11
 4 (  3 ):  0  1  5
 5 (  3 ):  6  7  10
 6 (  2 ):  7 10
 7 (  5 ):  8 10  12 11 13
 8 (  1 ): 13
 9 (  1 ):  0
10 (  0 ):
11 (  0 ):
12 (  2 ): 10 11
13 (  1 ): 12
```

Comment: Can you post contents of the topoOrder.dat?

Comment: Does the output of your program (the first for-loop) match what you expect?

Comment: Yes, the output in the first loop is perfect. I'm just having problems with the second loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work for you.

```
    public class Node {
     //public static  int inDegree, outDegree, adjNodes[]; // static was causing the problem
     public int inDegree, outDegree, adjNodes[];
    }


public class order{
    private static Node nodes[];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String dataFile = "file.dat";
        indegreeCompute(dataFile);
    }

    private static void indegreeCompute(String dataFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File(dataFile));
        nodes = new Node[scanFile.nextInt()];
        for(int l= 0 ; l <nodes.length ; l++) {
            nodes[l] = new Node();
        }
        while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
            scanFile.nextLine();
            int index = scanFile.nextInt();
            System.out.print("node = " + index);
            scanFile.next();
            int NumOutDegree = scanFile.nextInt();
            nodes[index].outDegree = NumOutDegree;
            System.out.print(" outDegree = " + nodes[index].outDegree);
            nodes[index].adjNodes = new int[NumOutDegree];
            scanFile.next();
            System.out.print(" adjNodes = [");
            for ( int i = 0; i < nodes[index].outDegree; i ++ ) {
                nodes[index].adjNodes[i] = scanFile.nextInt();
                if (i < nodes[index].outDegree - 1)
                    System.out.print(nodes[index].adjNodes[i] + ", ");
                else
                    System.out.print(nodes[index].adjNodes[i]);
            }
            System.out.print("]");
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i ++) {
            int outDegree = nodes[i].outDegree;
            for(int k = 0; k < outDegree; k ++) {
                int adjNode = nodes[i].adjNodes[k];
                nodes[adjNode].inDegree ++;
            }
        }
        scanFile.close();
    }
}
```

Problem was with the usage of the static variable in your auxiliary class.
You used class members there which were causing problems. i have changed them to object scope for understanding class scope please read following [Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should set nodes[index] = new Node() before assign any value to nodes[index]'s attributes. And the attributes of Node class should not be static, as every node should have its own values.

Because every element in your nodes array will be null unless you set a value to it. And in your code, when you set value to nodes[index].outDegree, you are setting value of Node.outDegree actually, and nodes[index] is still null. So in the end, you get a array which is full of null.

In summary, there is two mistakes here. Incorrectly use of static keywords and forget to initialize item of object array before using it.